# IE: Passing value from JSON object to onClick event

Tags: jquery, ajax, json, internet-explorer, onclick

I'm using jquery ajax. The server returns a JSON object and I am fetching the array.
Everything works fine in FF, of course, but somehow when i try to use this syntax:

```
$('#edituserLink').attr("onClick","edit('"+user[0]['USER_ID']+"');");
```

the onClick function wont have the value as an argument. Why?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Why aren't you using the standard [`.bind()` method](http://api.jquery.com/bind/)?

```
$('#edituserLink').bind('click', function() { edit(user[0]['USER_ID']); });
```

Some people prefer the shorthand form:

```
$('#edituserLink').click(function() { edit(user[0]['USER_ID']); });
```

but personally I regard that as a bad style. (Does the concept **bad style** even exist!? *Contradictio in terminis!*)

Comment: i tried your solution and my event is empty:

<a style="" onclick="edit('');" href="#" id="edituserLink">Edit User</a>

Comment: That depends on the availability of `user` at the time you bind this... if it's not available, there's a small problem. Closures. Is `user` a global variable? Then you can use `window.user` instead of `user`.

Comment: the element is always available. i just hide it and show it on occasions.

Comment: No, I mean the availability of the value of the **variable (array)** `user`. I can create a live example if you want to.

Comment: sorry for my late reply, i just came back from late lunch. sure i would appreciate a live example.

Comment: There you go, this is an example that works: http://jsfiddle.net/RNhcF/. Would you also like an example of a situation in which it doesn't work?

Answer (score 0):

Use [JQuery Events](http://api.jquery.com/category/events/) to do that (not the `onclick` attribute (case matters))...

Answer (score 0):

Instead of using the onClick event, use the jQuery click() event which is fully cross-browser compatible:

```
$('#edituserLink').click(function() {
     edit(user[0]['USER_ID']);
});
```